# C getting input with string, and converting part of it to an integer

Tags: c, string, int, atoi

So I'm doing what the title says with this code

```
else if(input[0] == 'i'){
        printf("This works");
        if(isspace(input[1])){
            x = 2;
            while(input[x] != '\0'){
                tempS[x - 2] = input[x];
            }
            inp = atoi(tempS);
            for(x = x-2; x >= 0; x--){
                tempS[x] == NULL;
            }
            insert(&linkedList, inp);
            printf("%i %s %c", inp, " sucessfully inserted.", '\n');
        }
    }
```

You can ignore the insert, basically I get user input which should be i and some number.

For example: i 27

Then the program should recognize that it's i in that else if, and take the number after the i.

Variable initialization is as follows.

```
char *input;
int inp = 0;
int x = 0;
char *tempS[255];
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The problem is that I get a segmentation fault before even the printf.

Comment: const char* is read only. Try allocating memory using malloc or calloc.

Comment: So where have you initialised what `input` points to?

Comment: the while loop looks infinite...  and the for loop's `tempS[x] == NULL;` does nothing...

Comment: Lol that loop. Beginner mistake, but that was not the issue with the segmentation fault. Looked at the answers given, and fixed the program. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck in an infinite loop.

```
 while(input[x] != '\0')
 {
          tempS[x - 2] = input[x];
 }
```

Add the instruction `x++;` So you can read the next element in the array input, otherwise, you are stuck in the position x = 2.

This `char *input`; it is only a pointer, you have to allocate memory to use it like you are currently using. Do the following:

```
input = malloc(sizeof(char) * N);
```

N is the number of elements that you want to have in the input array.

You are getting `segmentation fault` because you are trying to access memory, which was not allocated before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory (reserve memory) using malloc to your input pointer. Something like:

```
char *input = malloc( sizeof(char) * 128 ); //If you needs 128 positions
```

Take a look:

```
//  *---*---*---*---*------*
//  | i |   | 2 | 1 | \'0' |
//  *---*---*---*---*------*
//            ^----- You stay here.

while(input[x] != '\0'){
    tempS[x - 2] = input[x];
}
```

You declared `x = 2`, so You start in the 3rd position the char '2' (Char because you inputed it as a string), and it is not the null terminator '\0' so the while loop will execute the inner statement `tempS[x - 2] = input[x];` forever. So to fix this you should add an x modification kind of:

```
while(input[x] != '\0'){
    tempS[x - 2] = input[x];
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with while loop: It never ends as it does not increase x. It does not copy `'\0'` so `atoi` might crash. `input` is char array but `tempS` is char pointer array.

I don't immediately see reason for crash, unless `input[2]` actually is `'\0'` and while loop ends, in which case it is `atoi` which crashes, when you give it nonsense pointer array instead of string.  Crash might be in code you are not showing, considering how broken this code you show is...

Start by fixing compiler warnings, after turning on warnings. To turn them on, you need comppand line switch for compiler, for gcc just `-W` is a good start... Though real men compile with at least `-W -Wall -pedantic -std=c11` (replace `c11` with whichever version of C standard you want to use).